# Specify multiple cassandra port in application properties

Tags: spring, cassandra

I have following `application.properties`:

```
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=localhost
spring.data.cassandra.port=1112
```

In our information system 2 accessible ** cassandra nodes** *(one redirection is done on my laptop on **localhost:1112** and **localhost:1113**)*

**My question is:** How I can in `application.properties`, specify 2 differents host/port ? Because I already use
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=localhost:1112,localhost:1113
With different port and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the spring data [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#reference), have you tried:

```
cassandra.contactpoints=10.1.55.80:9042,10.1.55.81:9042
cassandra.keyspace=showcase
```

*You'll probably still need to prefix it with `spring.data`

Comment: It doesn't work, because isn't 'cassandra.contactpoints' in application property, but spring.data.cassandra.contact-points when  use this, I have the following error: [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster]: Factory method 'cassandraCluster' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to add contact point: localhost:1112
java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost:1112: Nom ou service inconnu

Comment: Can you please provide the actual snippet from application properties?

Comment: I add the configuration screenshot

Comment: Please add the sceenshot link in a comemnt here, not as a suggested edit to my answer.

Comment: not possible action from stack overflow sorry

Comment: In order to troubleshoot please use , not ; and also try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. 
For reference this: `spring.data.cassandra.<redacted>.contact-points=10.XXX.XXX.XXX,10.XXX.XXX.XXX,10.XXX.XXX.XXX` works with Spring Boot 2.1.3

Comment: Also, try avoiding images of code/config and instead copy-paste it using `code formatting`